# Calculating walking and ascends to the marathon milleage

Tags: running, running-training-plan, marathon

I'd like to be able to run marathons on the regular basis. Currently I'm running about 40 km per week, which enables me to run half marathons almost every week (mostly trail running, with about 800-1200 m ascend).

I've read a lot of advises with the conclusion that a healthy mileage for full marathon is about 60 km a week. I don't want to 'check' marathon for statistics, and then suffer for weeks. I want a healthy and fun experience.

However, running as much is for me problematic because of time planning. I need 1-2 days rest after running half marathon, some days fall back because of bad weather (I'm not acclimatized enough and catching a cold will pause my plan, so I'm careful). Some days I have enough time, I have a sport ban because I'm also a keen scuba diver. However, walking and hiking would be quite plausible on such days and I could include them in my training plan.

However, do the walks and ascents 'work' for running workout? If so, how I should calculate them to my mileage? For example, 2 km of walk 'count' as 1 km of run? 200 meters elevation as 1 km?
Or it's better to concentrate exclusively on running?
I want to stay on the safe side.

Comment: As hiking strengthens your hip/girdle region and therefore helps with your core/form, that sounds like a good alternative to running. (Even when I'm running, I tend to 'hike' up the steeper inclines anyways). For me, I double up my running days often but only if I am strict about pre-running warmups, post running stretches and depending on how my body feels: icing my knees a bit and epsom salt baths and roller sessions that night.